# How to configure and load database in innosetup

Tags: mysql, inno-setup

I'm using inno setup to create a setup for my java application. the application uses mysql server 5.5. how can i set user password and host? and how can i load my database? I found this code but something is wrong. can someone help me?

this statement is right, I use a procedure to check if mysql exists yet

```
Filename: "{reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.5,Location}\bin\mysqld.exe"; Parameters: --install; WorkingDir: "{reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.5,Location}\bin"; StatusMsg: "Sto installando il Servizio MySQL"; Description: "Installing MySQL Service"; Flags: runhidden; Check: MySQL_Is
```

But this are wrong in part

```
Filename: net.exe; Parameters: start mysql; StatusMsg: Sto Avviando il Servizio MySQL; Description: Avvio Servizio MySQL; Flags: runhidden

Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.5,Location}\bin\mysql.exe; Parameters: "-e ""insert into mysql.user(host,user,password) values ('localhost','root', PASSWORD('emmaus'));"" -u root "; WorkingDir: {tmp}; StatusMsg: Configurazione del Server della Base di Dati; Flags: runhidden

Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.5,Location}\bin\mysql.exe; Parameters: "-u root -h localhost -e ""create database ata";

Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.5,Location}\bin\mysql.exe; Parameters: "-e ""grant all privileges on ata.* to ata;"" -u root"; WorkingDir: {tmp}; StatusMsg: Configurazione Server Base di Dati; Flags: runhidden

Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.5,Location}\bin\mysql.exe; Parameters: "-e ""flush privileges;"" -u root"; WorkingDir: {tmp}; StatusMsg: Configurazione Server Base di Dati; Flags: runhidden

Filename: {reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.5,Location}\bin\mysql.exe; Parameters: "-u root -h localhost -e ""use ata; source ata.sql;"; WorkingDir: {tmp}; StatusMsg: Caricamento base di dati; Flags: runhidden  

Filename: netsh; Parameters: firewall add portopening TCP 3306 MySql; StatusMsg: Aplicando directivas de seguridad; MinVersion: 0,4.0; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,5.3; Description: Aplicando directivas de seguridad; Flags: runhidden
```

All process exit codes are = 1 except when I execute net.exe, process exit code is = 2

Comment: Wait, even value 1 looks somehow suspicious. Value of 0 is usually treated as success process exit code (not the rule, but usually is). Have you tried to run those command lines from console (if you're on Vista above in console running with admin privileges) ?

Comment: when I execute net.exe I have to run it as administrator. could be this one error in the script? the other statements i should execute in mysql command line but since i have mysql installed it ask me password so I think that I must pass password also as parameter to all statement

Comment: The problem with `net.exe` is that it's command line utility. For starting (as well as installing) services I would use the service control manager which if you use you immediately and quite precisely know what failed.

Comment: regarding the setting of user password and host and loading my database? any suggestions?

Comment: I've worked a little with MySQL, but again a simple rule. Run the service manually and execute the command lines for setting up the database in console. Once you get it to work, move it to the installer. I believe it will be described on many places on the Internet. Try to find one, test it and we can help you to port it to the Inno Setup. You know, the problem with Inno Setup questions is that they are very specifically asked. If someone would ask *"How to start a Windows service"*, everyone might pretty quickly find the answer. Many questions sounds to me just like *"Fix my script"*...

Comment: And please, don't take it personally :-) It was just my sigh about the trend of the questions here.

Comment: but I have asked for suggestions in fact, not to write code for me

Comment: Well, but what to suggest... I urge you to use Windows API for service starting. That `net start` command line executed from the `[Run]` section is like throwing a dice into the pit and waiting for the result. As the next thing I would find the way how to setup the database, test it in the console with manually started service and after that move the script to the `[Code]` section, because there you'll have more control over the execution results than in `[Run]` section.